# Should invokeOnComponent call pushComponentToEL to handle composite component

Tags: jsf, el, composite-component, mojarra

This is a discussion about the currently expected behavior of the JSF spec for the `UIComponent.invokeOnComponent()` method.

## Summary

I encountered an unexpected behavior while using 2 composite component with 2 different backing component because the `invokeOnComponent` method do not `pushComponentToEL` and the `ImplicitELResolver` rely on the `getCurrentCompositeComponent` to get the value of a #{cc.xx} property.

So, should the `invokeOnComponent` call the `pushComponentToEL` before iterating over children (as it does it before invoking the call back).
This is the workaround i implemented in the overriden `invokeOnComponent` method of my backing bean but i'm not quite sure of the consequences.

## In depths

Following is the use case i encountered with some simplified snippet to focus on the issue behind

#### The main facelet

Taking a simple facelet into account :

```
<html>
    <compositeComponent:comp1>
    <compositeComponent:comp2>
</html>
```

#### First composite component

The simplified code of the first custom composite component (comp1) :

```
<composite:interface componentType="comp1">
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <myComponentLib:myComponent />
</composite:implementation>
```

This one is backed by a bean we will call BACKING_COMPONENT_1

#### Second composite component

The simplified code of the first custom composite component (comp2) :

```
<composite:interface componentType="comp2">
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <p:dataTable value="#{cc.myList}" >
    </p:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
```

This one is backed by a bean we will call BACKING_COMPONENT_2

#### The scenario

The issue happens when the following scenario occurs :

1. `encodeAll` is called on the composite component 1
2. `encodeBegin` is called on the composite component 1
3. `pushComponentToEL` is called on the composite component 1
4. The "CURRENT_COMPOSITE_COMPONENT_STACK" is updated
5. `encodeAll` is called on myComponent
6. The "myComponent" renderer needs to find a component and thus call the `invokeOnComponent` on the `UIViewRoot`
7. The recursivity of the `invokeOnComponent` reach the `invokeOnComponent` method of the `DataTable` component inside the composite component 2
8. The `DataTable` need to resolve `#{cc.myList}` to keep visiting the tree with each row data.
9. The `ImplicitELResolver` try to resolve the `#{cc.xxx}` base. This is done using the `UIComponent.getCurrentCompositeComponent()` method which rely on the "CURRENT_COMPOSITE_COMPONENT_STACK" and resolve to BACKING_COMPONENT_1 (instead of the BACKING_COMPONENT_2)

#### The issue

In my opinion, this is some jsf spec issue that establish that the `invokeOnComponent` method should call the `pushComponentToEL` method and `popComponentToEL` before calling the callback if the clientId is the one searched and doesn't specify to do so when calling the `invokeOnComponent` method on the `facetsAndChildren`.

#### The workaround

As a workaround, I overridden the `invokeOnComponent` method in my composite component backing component to push and pop the component.

## Asking the real questions.

Should the push and pop mechanism be used when calling `invokeOnComponent` method on `facetsAndChildrens` ?
And will this workaround can cause me some unseen issue in other cases ?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? This is a bug.

Comment: I found this bug on mojarra 2.1.28 but just checked and it's also present in the master. We also use myfaces which indeed seems to push and pop for before and after calling `invokeOnComponent` on children. If this is a bug, this is a SPEC bug and not an RI bug as it does what the javadoc spec says.

Comment: I just hit the same problem and noticed that `invokeOnComponent` is wrong in Mojarra (testet up to 2.3.14). It's indeed a bug as a comment on `findComponent` tells that `invokeOnComponent` has a fully valid tree traversal context (it even explicitly mentions `implicit objects like #{component}`. `#{cc}` is also a implicit object). Therefore it is a RI bug, isn't it?